# What is ratio of paper drawing to GameMaker Studio drawing?

Tags: game-maker

I was wondering, if I have character/object on paper (A4 format with grid) and I wish to transfer it to GameMaker Studio, then what should the ratio be between them?

I assume it can't be 1:1 or it will be too small on screen.

To clarify, by ratio I mean 1 square of grid on A4 paper, that I treat as a pixel to pixel in GameMaker Studio.

Comment: Isnt Gamemaker using a grid system as well? Have you tried to use one A4 cell to one Gamemaker cell?

Comment: Units and scales in game engines are typically arbitrary. One game might follow the convention "1 unit = 1 meter" while another will say "1 unit = 1 foot" or "1 unit = 1 x main character height". Usually you can apply scaling, camera, or viewpoint tweaks to make the content appear any scale you want on screen, independent of the number of units it measure in the game world (though you may face pixelation if you blow up a raster image too big)

Comment: This question seems to have more to do with your scanner than GameMaker Studio itself. Are you actually talking about scanning your drawings to make sprites? If your scanner's resolution is 300 DPI that means 1 inch on the paper would come out as 300 pixels! But you can resize the image after scanning it, so you can use any ratio you want.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how many cells the A4 has. I suppose there are a few common ones. Yet, you can even consider a custom grid for your particular needs.

And I don't know how big do you want the result to be on screen. Keep in mind that this is also related to the pixel resolution, screen size, and scaling.

So, you see, I cannot prescribe you a number.

---

But you do know. You have the A4 paper in question, and the size on screen is for you to decide.

Thus: make an A4 worth of pixels at one to one ratio. Then compare it with the size you want. If it is a good result, then that's it.

If it isn't, then you can decide if you are going to use a different ratio based on the size comparison between what you want and what you got. Or if you are going to use the one to one ratio but scale the result afterwards via software.

And if you are yet to produce the drawings in paper, then you can consider printing a custom grid. Or perhaps you can cut and glue some of those A4 to make the size you need. Or make the sprite fully digitally, no paper involved. Or some other solution I might not have thought of… To the strength of the artist and the limitations of the budget.